# Getting a error out of memory in android

Tags: android, json

In my application i can login by sending a request to local server using json. I am saving all the data of json using shared preferences. and after clicking on logout button it is coming back to login activity and deleting all the data from shared preferences. But when after login i am going to login using any other email_id,  password it is showing me following error:

```
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:271)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:417)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at com.example.androidhive.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:59)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at com.example.androidhive.library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:37)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at com.example.androidhive.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:93)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-02 13:02:25.161: E/AndroidRuntime(1061):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using these piece of code to login:

```
 btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            Log.d("Button", "Login");
            json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                                getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(share_pref_file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("jsondata", json.toString());
                        editor.commit();

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        // userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),
                                json.getString(KEY_UID));
                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                DashboardActivity.class);
                        dashboard.putExtra("email", email);
                        dashboard.putExtra("password", password);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg
                                .setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And Here the code of JSONParser.java:59:

```
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
```

and th 2nd error code line is:

```
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}
```

So can you tell me what is going wrong for what i cant login second time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your data coming from server? check logcat

Comment: yes i have mentioned it..